# SwipeListView in SlidingPaneLayout doesn't intercept item click events

Tags: android, listview, swipe, ontouchlistener, swipe-gesture

I have a swipelistview in a custom SlidingPaneLayout. Here is the slider definition.

```
<com.tab.mobile.utilities.CustomSlider
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/leftPane"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="gone"/>

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/rightPane"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top" />

</com.tab.mobile.utilities.CustomSlider>
```

Here is the slider class definition.

```
public class CustomSlider extends SlidingPaneLayout {
    private boolean canSlide;
    private int orientation;

    private static final String TAG_NAME = "SlidingPaneLayout";

    public CustomSlider (Context context) {
         super(context);
    }

    public CustomSlider (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
         this.orientation = orientation;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG_NAME, "intercepting touch event");

        return !canSlide ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) : canSlide;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(!canSlide) {
           getChildAt(1).dispatchTouchEvent(event);
           return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        return super.performClick();
    }

    public void setCanSlide(boolean canSlide) {
        this.canSlide = canSlide;
    }
 }
```

And the swipeListview initialization in the layout xml is:

```
com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
    android:id="@+id/enquiryListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
    swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
    swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
    swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false"
    />
```

In the code, I am setting the adapter for swipeListview

```
enquiryView.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_BOTH); 
enquiryView.setSwipeActionLeft(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL); 
enquiryView.setSwipeActionRight(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);
enquiryView.setOffsetLeft(value);
enquiryView.setAnimationTime(50); // Animation time
enquiryView.setSwipeOpenOnLongPress(false);
enquiryView.setAdapter(adapter);

enquiryView.setOnItemClickListener(listener); //this is not working. no events are coming to handler
```

I need two actions to happen.

a. Tapping a list item should drill into other screen

b. Long tap a list item should call openAnimate

I reckon swipe gestures can not be used as it will overlap with that of the slider. How do I approach this problem? Is there anything I am lacking?

Thanks,
Renjith

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **setOnItemClickListener** you can use SwipeListView's own **setSwipeListViewListener**. Something like this should work for you:

```
enquiryView
        .setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onListChanged() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMove(int position, float x) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(int position, int action,
                    boolean right) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
                // this is where you want to use click event on listview
            }

            @Override
            public void onClickBackView(int position) {
                // 
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

            }

        });
```

If this doesnot work for you let me know.

Comment: I did that! However, long tap triggers onClickFrontView(int) method